# PIL (Python 3.4) modifies RGV value

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb

Here is a code that create a little 10×10 picture, all green, in jpg format:

```
import PIL.Image as img
im = img.new('RGB', (10,10), (0,255,0))
print(np.array(im))

[[[  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]]
...
```

So, it is ok. But if the file is saved then opened:

```
im.save(chemin+"essai.jpg")  
it = np.array(img.open(chemin+"essai.jpg"))
print(it)

array([[[  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1],
        [  0, 255,   1]],
...
```

Why is there 1 in the Blue component?

It is the same if I do a red picture `[255,0,0]` which gives after saving and opening: `[254,0,0]`. So why 254?

It seems to be when saving and not when loading because if I open the saved file in a software like photoshop, the color is already modified.

If someone has an answer. (And sorry for my bad english). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

JPG is a lossy format. Lossless image formats like PNG work.

```
im.save(chemin+"essai.png")
```

Supported image file formats are documented [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html).

Comment: And "lossy" means you don't always get back the same pixel values that you started with.

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is that happen only for values equal to 255. For example a color [128,100,200] will be saved with exactly the same number...